# Wait for the window to complete resizing itself, and then do something in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So basically, I am trying to do some calculations when the window is being resized. Right now, my code looks like this:

```
var appWindow = angular.element($window);
appWindow.bind('resize', function () {
    // Do Something
});
```

However, right now the function runs upto 30 times sometimes, so its quite slow. Any way to fire it just once when the window is done resizing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method for accomplishing this:

```
var resizeTimeout;

appWindow.bind('resize', function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
    resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        // when the window stops resizing, this function will execute
    }, 200);
});
```

Basically, when the event fires it clears the existing timeout and then sets a timeout. When the window has stopped resizing, the last timeout created from the `setTimeout` call is not cleared, and therefore executes after the specified duration in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to track the window 'resize' event with a timeout and then run the function when it has been completely resized:

```
var resizing;
var appWindow = angular.element($window);
appWindow.bind('resize', function () {
    clearTimeout(resizing);
    resizing= setTimeout(function() {
      // Do Something
    }, 250);
});
```

This is not extremely elegant, you can also use the $timeout service Angular gives you.